Browser not displaying JavaScript graphics, instead displaying the code
I have installed Node.js modules and canvas-sketch library for the project.
When I try to open the sketch.js file on the browser I see the code instead of the graphics.
The file contents:
const canvasSketch = require('canvas-sketch');

const settings = {
  dimensions: [ 2048, 2048 ]
};

const sketch = () => {
  return ({ context, width, height }) => {
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  };
};

canvasSketch(sketch, settings);

The folder structure
How can I fix this?
It should display the blue rectangle on the screen, but I get code lines instead.

The browser doesn't just run javascript by itself. You're supposed to load your HTML file which includes this javascript code.

You need to (re-)start the development server.
Run canvas-sketch sketches/sketch-1.js (replace it with the sketch you want to load) to start the server from the command line or terminal.
If there aren't any errors you'll get a message info Server running at http://[some local address] where you can view the sketch.

The answer to your question is that browsers are for running HTML files. For example, this is a link to a JavaScript file: https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.5/socket.io.min.js.
It displays the JavaScript code, but it doesn't run it. To run it, you first must put it in an HTML file, like this:
<script src="/your file path/yourfile"> </script>

Or:
<script>
    <!-- Some JavaScript code -->
</script>

